# EditText does not return expected value

Tags: android, android-edittext

Following is the layout xml :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/T1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
    <TableRow>
        <EditText android:text="Enter SKU Id"
            android:id="@+id/E1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
        <Button android:text="Search" 
            android:id="@+id/B1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I am trying to get the value of `EditText`. Default value of edit text is *Enter SKU Id*, I change this to some string but when using following code it still gives me the default string.

```
E11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.E1);
sku = E11.getText().toString();
```

How can I get the current value?

Answer (score 1):

Get the current String by using `E11.getText().toString()` is fine, the problem sould be something else.

By the way, if you want to put some hint String in `EditText`, use `android:hint` attribute instead of `android:text`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method on your EditText and make your class implement or define an inner class implementing the TextWatcher class: